# Sum of subdocuments in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Currently I have this schema.

```
var cartSchema = new Schema({
    userPurchased: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'users'},
    products: [
        {
            product: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'products'},
            size: {type: String, required: true},
            quantity: {type: Number, required: true},
            subTotal: {type: Number, required: true}
        }
    ],
    totalPrice: {type: Number, default: 0, required: true}
});
```

Example of db record

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "586f4be94d3e481378469a08"
    },
    "userPurchased": {
        "$oid": "586dca1f5f4a7810fc890f97"
    },
    "totalPrice": 0,
    "products": [
        {
            "product": {
                "$oid": "58466e8e734d1d2b0ceeae00"
            },
            "size": "m",
            "quantity": 5,
            "subTotal": 1995,
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "586f4be94d3e481378469a09"
            }
        },
        {
            "subTotal": 1197,
            "quantity": 3,
            "size": "m",
            "product": {
                "$oid": "58466e8e734d1d2b0ceeae01"
            },
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "586f4ef64d3e481378469a0a"
            }
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0
}
```

Is there any way to sum all the subTotal and put it in the total price field? Right now I am thinking about aggregate function but I doubt it will be the right approach in here. I guess I need an update query and sum method at the same time. Can anyone help me in here?

Comment: How about a virtual property where you just add up all the prices of the products? I don't see the need to store the total price too.

Comment: I think the aggregate funcions, or map reduce functions, is the best solution. MongoDB has a grate aggregate and map redece framework. ake a look thi this example https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/map-reduce/

Comment: @Camo can you give me an example? i think it was a great idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the **[`aggregate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.aggregate)** function, you can run the following pipeline which uses the [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) operator to get the desired results:

```
const results = await Cart.aggregate([
    { "$addFields": {
        "totalPrice": {
            "$sum": "$products.subTotal"
        }
    } },
]);

console.log(JSON.stringify(results, null, 4));
```

and the corresponding update operation follows:

```
db.carts.updateMany(
   { },
   [
        { "$set": {
            "totalPrice": {
                "$sum": "$products.subTotal"
            }
        } },
    ]
)
```

Or if using MongoDB 3.2 and earlier versions, where [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) is available in the $group stage only, you can do

```
const pipeline = [
    { "$unwind": "$products" },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "products": { "$push": "$products" },
            "userPurchased": { "$first": "$userPurchased" },
            "totalPrice": { "$sum": "$products.subTotal" }
        }
    }
]

Cart.aggregate(pipeline)
    .exec(function(err, results){
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(results, null, 4));
    })
```

---

In the above pipeline, the first step is the **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** operator

```
{ "$unwind": "$products" }
```

which comes in quite handy when the data is stored as an array. When the unwind operator is applied on a list data field, it will generate a new record for each and every element of the list data field on which unwind is applied. It basically flattens the data.

This is a necessary operation for the next pipeline stage, the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** step where you group the flattened documents by the `_id` field, thus effectively regrouping the denormalised documents back to their original schema.

The **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline operator is similar to the SQL's `GROUP BY` clause. In SQL, you can't use `GROUP BY` unless you use any of the aggregation functions. The same way, you have to use an aggregation function in MongoDB (called accumulators) as well. You can read more about the [accumulators here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#accumulator-operator).

In this **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** operation, the logic to calculate the `totalPrice` and returning the original fields is through the [accumulators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#accumulator-operator). You get the`totalPrice` by summing up each individual `subTotal` values per group with **`$sum`** as:

```
"totalPrice": { "$sum": "$products.subTotal }
```

The other expression

```
"userPurchased": { "$first": "$userPurchased" },
```

will return a `userPurchased` value from the first document for each group using **`$first`**. Thus effectively rebuilding the original document schema before the **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)**

One thing to note here is when executing a pipeline, MongoDB pipes operators into each other. "Pipe" here takes the Linux meaning: the output of an operator becomes the input of the following operator. The result of each operator is a new collection of documents. So Mongo executes the above pipeline as follows:

```
collection | $unwind | $group => result
```

---

As a side note, to help with understanding the pipeline or to debug it should you get unexpected results, run the aggregation with just the first pipeline operator. For example, run the aggregation in mongo shell as:

```
db.cart.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$products" }
])
```

Check the result to see if the `products` array is deconstructed properly. If that gives the expected result, add the next:

```
db.cart.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$products" },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "products": { "$push": "$products" },
            "userPurchased": { "$first": "$userPurchased" },
            "totalPrice": { "$sum": "$products.subTotal" }
        }
    }
])
```

Repeat the steps till you get to the final pipeline step.

---

If you want to update the field then you can add the **[`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#pipe._S_out)** pipeline stage as the last step. This will write the resulting documents of the aggregation pipeline to the same collection, thus technically updating the collection.

```
var pipeline = [
    { "$unwind": "$products" },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "products": { "$push": "$products" },
            "userPurchased": { "$first": "$userPurchased" },
            "totalPrice": { "$sum": "$products.subTotal" }
        }
    },
    { "$out": "cart" } // write the results to the same underlying mongo collection
]
```

---

**UPDATE**

To do both the update and query, you could then issue a `find()` call in the aggregate callback to get the updated json i.e.

```
Cart.aggregate(pipeline)
    .exec(function(err, results){
        if (err) throw err;
        Cart.find().exec(function(err, docs){
            if (err) return handleError(err);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(docs, null, 4));
        })
    })
```

Using Promises, you could do this alternatively as

```
Cart.aggregate(pipeline).exec().then(function(res)
    return Cart.find().exec();
).then(function(docs){  
    console.log(JSON.stringify(docs, null, 4));
});
```

Comment: Thanks @chridam for an awesome explanation. I have tried this on my terminal but the output of the totalPrice is 0. Can't find out why.

Comment: Let's debug the pipeline to find out why. When you run the pipeline with just the `$unwind` as `db.cart.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$products" }
])`, do you get the intended results? Are there some fields in your `products` subdocument that do not have numericals values for `subTotal`? Could be that `subTotal` is a string?

Comment: the result of unwinding is as desired. group by id returns two objectId as expected. then I skipped the line with products and userPurchased as I am a little bit confused. I included the totalPrice then it returns as expected too. When I tried everything IN ORDER earlier, totalPrice returns 0. I think it is on the line where the products and userPurchased conflicts. should I put calculating of totalPrice first then repopulating the schema again? do you think there is an effect?

Comment: I think I just mistyped some code that causes it to misbehave. Now it works on my terminal. I will try to implement this on my code. Thank you so much for this very intuitive answer!

Comment: No problem :) Glad I could help in some way.

Comment: can I ask one more thing? If I put $out operator on the last line, the results in db.cart.aggregate is just [] and empty array. but when I remove the $out it returns a normal json object. I need the json object and the $out operator for updating the collection. How can I do that?

Comment: Good question, got me thinking. I have updated the answer with an approach.

Comment: sweet! I'll take a look and try. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I can't really say whether this approach is better than the aggregation, but in case you want to do it with virtuals:

```
cartSchema.virtual('totalPrice').get(function () {
     return this.products.map(p => p.subTotal).reduce((a, b) => a + b);
});
```

But care:

> If you use toJSON() or toObject() (or use JSON.stringify() on a mongoose document) mongoose will not include virtuals by default. Pass { virtuals: true } to either toObject() or toJSON()