# Nested Array Sum / Count MongoDB Express

Tags: mongodb, express, nested, aggregate

All, although this question was marked as a duplicate, I'm still having issues,  searching through the example, I'm still not able to figure out how to perform a sum / count of a nested array in mongodb please see below.

I'm using mongoose autopopulate to store the ids within the arrays and display them when performing a find.

I want to lookup the employee.discussions array and return the sum of occurrences on my Discussion collection. I'm able to  get the count of discussions, but not the sum of discussions.occurrece.

My query:

```
//Show Single Route
router.get("/:id", isLoggedin, function(req, res){


            var pipeline = [
                { "$match" : {"employeeuserid" : 'jbarmak' }},
                { "$unwind": "$discussions" },
                {
                    "$group": {
                        "_id": null,
                        "eventwaiver": { "$sum": 1 }
                    }
                }
            ];

            Employee.aggregate(pipeline)
                .exec(function(err, results){
                    if (err) throw err;
                    console.log(results);
                });


            Employee.findById(req.params.id, function (err, foundEmployee){
                if(err){
                    res.redirect('/employee');
                } else {
                    res.render('employees/show', {employee: foundEmployee});
                }
            });
});
```

Employee Collection

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5ad7cf42729b4c08ae721603"
    },
    "author": {
        "id": {
            "$oid": "5ac2f25bbfb8ef001411fd01"
        },
        "username": "gmotta"
    },
    "qcerrors": [
        {
            "$oid": "5add3bc296d0a6265c04c674"
        }
    ],
    "employeesapnumber": 10001186,
    "employeeuserid": "jbarmak",
    "firstname": "jaouad",
    "lastname": "barmaki",
    "warehouseid": "1090",
    "shift": 2,
    "department": "Picking",
    "position": "Contractor",
    "hiredate": {
        "$date": "2010-12-02T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "myimage": "myimage-1524092737893.PNG",
    "__v": 50,
    "discussions": [
        {
            "$oid": "5add0bf211e77d08106edc9b"
        },
        {
            "$oid": "5add0c2311e77d08106edc9d"
        },
        {
            "$oid": "5add136511e77d08106edca1"
        },
        {
            "$oid": "5add148467850c0ca35ff74a"
        },
        {
            "$oid": "5add14a967850c0ca35ff74c"
        },
        {
            "$oid": "5add1eb9579cf80d86310f7d"
        },
        {
            "$oid": "5adecf7e0264cc0e7aada389"
        }
    ],
    "safetyincidents": [
        {
            "$oid": "5adeb5260264cc0e7aada385"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I sum the occurrences in the nested array and console.log the result?

Dicussion collection:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5adfb054a590b10eef004b63"
    },
    "author": {
        "id": {
            "$oid": "5ac2f25bbfb8ef001411fd01"
        },
        "username": "gmotta"
    },
    "datetime": {
        "$date": "2018-02-02T14:02:00.000Z"
    },
    "reasondiscussion": "None",
    "reasontimeoff": "Bereavement",
    "warning": "None",
    "hours": 8,
    "plannedunplanned": "Unplanned",
    "occurrence": 1,
    "description": "I'm calling in because  I'm sick.",
    "shift": 1,
    "department": "Pallet-Pack",
    "employeeid": "tkane",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Comment: You are essentially looking for [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/). Once you have the "join", then you can `$sum` the properties from the related document.

Comment: looks like we already have similar question answered on the forum.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41501752/sum-of-subdocuments-in-mongoose

Comment: Thank you!!! I'll check it out.

Comment: I'm still having issues, I could not get it to work by searching through the examples, I added some more info to my question.

Comment: Nothing in your "added info" shows `$lookup`, and that's the only thing your question actually asks as well as exactly what the linked duplicates are showing you. So you need to actually implement something already demonstrated to you. You have not done that.